# Seemingly contradictory reactivity in Svelte assignment to array element

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm new to Svelte and experimenting with a trivial Tic Tac Toe implementation.

I'm confused why reactivity is working when I update the elements of an array, contrary to the documentation which says that its necessary to assign the array to itself to trigger subscription notifications.

I can't setup a REPL for the application as I'm using Typescript, the Svelte REPL seems to only support JS, so I'm hoping that this main Board.svelte file is sufficient, as this seems to be where the issue lies.

The question I have relates to the `tiles` array, which is updated in a click handler.  Note that the click handler is not reactive (no `$:` and as incline function rather than an arrow function), but modifications to `tiles[index]` seem to cause reactivity, because the UI updates, and so also does the `gameOver` variable which is computed whenever the board changes (it returns either `undefined` if the game is in progress, or an object containing the winning player and the tile indexes that comprise the win).

Note that the `isWin` function is written with reactivity - if I remove the `$:` it stops updating the `isWin` prop on the tile, which controls whether the tile is highlighted on game over.

This seems to be contradictory - `gameOver` needs `tiles` passing as an argument and to be marked reactive or it won't react on tile updates (as I would expect).  `isWin` needs to be reactive, or it won't cause `Tile` to re-render.

The but I can't explain is why `click` managed to cause updates to be fired, when the array itself is not updating (only the element).  NB: Removing references to `gameOver` and `activePlayer` don't make any difference to subscription notifications on `tiles`.

I specifically avoided using svelte/stores in this implementation.  I got in a mess trying to use them and stripped it back to basic reactivity and found that did everything I needed, and I'm not clear if the 'array = array' convention is different when using stores vs reactive vars.

I'd really like to understand this better before moving forward.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Tile from './Tile.svelte'
    import Result from "./Result.svelte"
    import Reset from "./Reset.svelte"
    import type { GameOver, Player } from "./types"
    import { getGameOver } from "./getGameOver"

    let activePlayer: Player = 'X'
    const tiles: Array<Player | undefined> = Array(9).fill(undefined)

    let gameOver: GameOver | undefined
    $: gameOver = getGameOver(tiles)

    let isWin: (index: number) => boolean
    $: isWin = (index: number) => {
        return gameOver?.winLine?.includes(index) ?? false
    }

    function click(index: number) {
        if (!gameOver && tiles[index] === undefined) {
            tiles[index] = activePlayer
            activePlayer = activePlayer === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        for (const index in tiles) {
            tiles[index] = undefined
        }
        activePlayer = 'X'
    }

</script>

<div class="board" class:gameOver={!!gameOver}>
    <Result gameOver={gameOver} activePlayer={activePlayer}/>

    <div class="tiles">
        {#each tiles as tile, i}
            <Tile player={tile} isWin={isWin(i)} click={() => click(i)}/>
        {/each}
    </div>
    <Reset reset={reset}/>
</div>

<style>
    .tiles {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning an element of an array is just like assigning any other object property, so the array will be marked as dirty.

What the documentation is warning about is the use of functions which internally change the array, e.g. `push` or `pop`. This would require Svelte to know what the various functions do to keep reactivity.

---

Svelte analyzes the code to see where modifications of state happen, e.g.

```html
<script>
    let items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
</script>

<button on:click={() => items[0] = '!'}>
    Change Item 0
</button>
```

Here the compiled code for the click handler will contain additional logic to invalidate `items`, because its property `'0'` has been modified.

```js
function instance($$self, $$props, $$invalidate) {
    let items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    const click_handler = () => $$invalidate(0, items[0] = '!', items);
    return [items, click_handler];
}
```

This happens regardless of whether the object is an array or not, or whether additional nested properties are added.

Comment: I understood that to be about dimensional changes (changes to `length` rather than to array element updates.  I'm guessing therefore that Svelte hooks the index accessor to know if an element value is reassigned.

Comment: You can look at the compiled output to see the details. As i said, this is no different that any other property: You can change objects which are not arrays like this as well: `obj[property]`. Svelte will invalidate any object whose indexer is used in an assignment.

Comment: `length` is reactive as well, by the way, as long as you change it directly. ([REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/132a309918f9401086aa411ea8f2e971?version=3.49.0))

Comment: @DaveMeehan Also, to clean up potential confusion: Svelte does not "hook" anything. It generates code based on the template, injecting the necessary logic to invalidate the state of the component and cause DOM updates/re-rendering. The state objects themselves are not being modified with additional functionality at all.